# Connection Error - Query SQL database on databricks SQLwarehouse

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I want to query SQL tables in databricks sqlwarehouse from local python setup.
I created a new sqlwarehouse in azure databricks, used the python example inorder to query sample tables. After several minutes it fails with connection error. I had generated fresh token too.

I create a new workspace in Azure Databricks and used default sqlwarehouse instance. Now, I want to query sample tables from local python script. For this, I use the sample code provided by databricks inorder to query tables in Python. Following is the sample code from databricks itself:

```
    from databricks import sql
    import os
    connection = sql.connect(
        server_hostname="adb-2485588098372366.6.azuredatabricks.net",
        http_path="/sql/1.0/warehouses/c62cc104e136a5bd",
        access_token="dapif5d0c1ff887631d9ef0aea86d08446b3")

    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * from range(10)")
    print(cursor.fetchall())

    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

I this code from here:

[image]

I even generated fresh access token for this purpose.  When I tested the script, it fails with connection error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vishalgupta/PycharmProjects/ds-chat-app/src/test.py", line 199, in <module>
    connection = sql.connect(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vishalgupta/PycharmProjects/ds-chat-app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/databricks/sql/__init__.py", line 84, in connect
    return Connection(server_hostname, http_path, access_token, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vishalgupta/PycharmProjects/ds-chat-app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/databricks/sql/client.py", line 232, in __init__
    self._open_session_resp = self.thrift_backend.open_session(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vishalgupta/PycharmProjects/ds-chat-app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/databricks/sql/thrift_backend.py", line 578, in open_session
    response = self.make_request(self._client.OpenSession, open_session_req)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vishalgupta/PycharmProjects/ds-chat-app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/databricks/sql/thrift_backend.py", line 507, in make_request
    self._handle_request_error(error_info, attempt, elapsed)
  File "/Users/vishalgupta/PycharmProjects/ds-chat-app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/databricks/sql/thrift_backend.py", line 337, in _handle_request_error
    raise network_request_error
databricks.sql.exc.RequestError: Error during request to server
```

Any tips or help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you once try like this

Comment: import pyodbc
jdbc_url = "jdbc:databricks://adb-1094283832228749.9.azuredatabricks.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=/sql/1.0/warehouses/b6995785e608ae40"
connection = pyodbc.connect(jdbc_url)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM sales(10)")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)